# Mapbox NSInternalInconsistencyException showing RMMapView on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, mapbox

Having a spot of trouble trying to get the native iOS Mapbox view working on an actual device (3rd gen iPad, iOS 7.1).

```
dprintf( "RMMapboxSource\n" );
RMMapboxSource * tileSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithMapID:mystyle];

dprintf( "RMMapView\n" );
RMMapView * mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,900,450) andTilesource:tileSource];

dprintf( "addChild\n" );
// ... mapView then added to view hierarchy

dprintf( "setPage\n" );
// ... then make visible
```

Everything works great in the simulator. But trying to run on an actual iPad results in the following.

```
RMMapboxSource
RMMapView
addChild
setPage
2014-04-01 15:41:21.879 Protraak[1179:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UIView layoutSubviews], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:5326
2014-04-01 15:41:21.881 Protraak[1179:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'layout should have been successfully accomplished'
```

A Google search for "layout should have been successfully accomplished" came up blank.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the latest `develop` branch and see if that works for you?